# Javascript Password Checker

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I have a password check using javascript and an if loop. However, when I enter a string that is not javascript, no alert is displayed. Here is my code.

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function password_prompt() {

    var password = window.prompt("Please enter the correct password ", ""); //password = javascript
    if (password == "javascript") {
    var x = window.confirm("Please confirm you want to enter the webpage!");
        if (x != 1) {
        window.close();
        window.open("https://www.google.com/");
    }
    if (password != "javascript") {
        window.alert("You entered the wrong password! Page will now close!");
    window.close();
    window.open("about:blank");
        }

    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: indent your code and you'll see

Comment: OT: javascript authentification is such a bad idea... :)

Comment: Hardcoded password is a bad idea

Comment: @EduardVoid client side authentication is bad. It's perfectly fine in NodeJS ;)

Comment: @Endless do you think, that somebody asking this question knows something about NodeJS ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```html
<script type = "text/javascript">
function password_prompt() {

    var password = prompt("Please enter the correct password ", ""); //password = javascript
    if (password == "javascript") {
    var x = confirm("Please confirm you want to enter the webpage!");
        if (x != 1) {
        window.close();
        window.open("https://www.google.com/");
    }
    if (password != "javascript") {
        alert("You entered the wrong password! Page will now close!");
    window.close();
    window.open("about:blank");
        }

    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: When I enter something different from javascript, the alert is not displayed

Comment: set  console.log(password) for will see password current value

Comment: if password value is not equal "javascript" restart the browser or shoose another browser

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
function password_prompt() {

    var password = window.prompt("Please enter the correct password ", ""); //password = javascript
    if (password == "javascript") {
        var x = window.confirm("Please confirm you want to enter the webpage!");
        if (x != 1) {
            window.close();
            window.open("https://www.google.com/");
        }
    }
    if (password != "javascript") {
        window.alert("You entered the wrong password! Page will now close!");
        window.close();
        window.open("about:blank");
    }
}
</script>
```